# Android Studio Minify with R8 run indefinitely "minifyReleaseWithR8"

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-r8

The last version of my app was built with Gradle 7.2.0 and the minification was running fine. Forward a few months, I am trying to build the same application with the same libraries with the same proguard rules as before and my build run indefinitely on the task "minifyReleaseWithR8". I've let it run a couple hours on 4gigs of ram.

Since I don't get any error or logs, I'm not quite sure how I should go about troubleshooting this issue.

I tried to find some answers about this but all I find is build optimization tips.

I also tried to add -keep to all classes of my project just to see if I could fix it by removing one at a time.It didn't work even with the -keep.

Comment: This looks like an issue in R8, and I suggest that you file an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788. Your version of AGP is quite old with the latest stable being 8.1, so you could also try to upgrade AGP first.

Comment: I read over what I ask and it's not clear. I tried to build with AGP 8 and Gradle build tools 8.x and I was getting the infiniteloop/deadlock. I ended up having to go back to 7.2 to be able to build it. Problem is, I will have to upgrade at some point and I really don't know what breaks it.

Comment: Thanks for trying to update. What I would like you to do is to file an issue on our issue tracker (issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788), so we can work together to figure out why you are seeing compilations which does not terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a duplicate of https://issuetracker.google.com/304746905.

We have also fixed another issue where R8 did not terminate, https://issuetracker.google.com/307761442.

If anybody runs into R8 not terminating please check out these two issues.